# How do I disable chrome_annotation tags?

Tags: google-chrome

At least on iPadOS 17.2, Chrome is inserting these <chrome_annotation … > tags. This occurs when I use a [Lit](https://lit.dev/) component to render a string into the result of a render() call. The string is nested inside some other html tags (mostly divs). Chrome is doing this when there is an “@“ character in the inserted string. It breaks the Lit rendering on subsequent renders, besides looking like not-what-I-want.

How do I tell Chrome to not do this?